# How to get an offset border round the visible part of the browser window

Tags: css

I've got a set up similar to this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iAJnx where the main content is rather long. What I want to do is to put a border round the visible part of the screen as in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm3DJ.png

What I want to do is to create 4 divs that are positioned at the edges of the screen, but I'm struggling both with the positioning and giving the divs height and width without content. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Note: I've already tried using an overlay, but it makes the content non-clickable.

Comment: I am assuming you still want it to be fluid when you resize the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="border-box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { position: relative; }

.border-box {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 100px #fff;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

**How it works:**
I absolutely positioned an overlay with borders, that will stick the edges of the screen by using top, bottom, left, right definitions.  To make the content below selectable, you set `pointer-events: none;` on the overlay.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxJbh

If you want to achieve the same results without adding additional HTML markup, you can use the `:before` sudo selector to prepend a block to the body.  Simply add this CSS and it will produce the same results:

```
body:before {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 100px #fff;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BDhql

Comment: Add this line too: `box-shadow: 0 0 100px 100px #fff;` (this will *fill* the margin the box leaves)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know if he wanted to hide the text outside of the blue area.  I've added your suggestion to the example though, it makes sense.

Comment: Perfect, thanks guys - that's exactly what I was after. Much tidier than I was planning.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set in your content id (**#content**)

> `border:4px solid blue;`
>   `min-width:700px;`  //change accordingly.
>   `min-height:1600px` //change accordingly

The above code will fix the problem of border as well as the height & width you want to set without having any content.